# jQuery Clone Then InsertAfter Cloning Numerous Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I'm trying to create a dynamic form to demonstrate to a business partner.

The goal is to be able to add select elements as necessary when the button is clicked. However, when it's clicked it duplicates the template twice, not just once.

Here are just a few of the variations of the code I've tried and [here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3qk7aLu/):

```
$("#serviceTemplate").eq(0).clone().insertAfter(".serviceField:last");

$("#serviceTemplate").clone().insertAfter(".serviceField:last");

$("#serviceTemplate").eq(0).clone().insertAfter($(".serviceField").last());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is simple since you are using `$('select').material_select();` to initiate all `select` element (therefore it is unique and clone it might have some unexpected issue).

Solution:

1. When you click `ADD` call `$('select').material_select('destroy');` to destroy and get the original element
2. now you can clone it and append
3. initiate all select use `$('select').material_select();`

(Note: since the clone will also copy the `id="serviceTemplate"` it is a bad practice since id should be unique. Remove the id and use something like `$(".serviceField").first()` to target the original element.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});

$("#addBtn").click(function() {
  $('select').material_select('destroy');
  $(".serviceField").last().after($(".serviceField").first().clone());
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

form {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

nav li a {
  padding: 0 .65rem;
}

nav,
#search {
  background: #eee !important;
}

.brand-logo h4 {
  color: #444;
}

.brand-logo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

#table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form name="demo" id="demo" class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
          <input type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Your name..." />
          <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
          <input type="text" class="validate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required/>

          <label>Desired Appointment Date</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row serviceField">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m3">

          <select class="service" required>
       <option value="" disabled selected>-Please Select Service-</option>
       <option value="1" data-cost="90">Virus Removal - $90</option>
       <option value="2" data-cost="20">PC Tune-Up - $20</option>
     </select>

          <label>Service Required</label>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m3">
          <div id="addBtn" class="btn black white-text">Add Another Service</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is one issue with this, and that's the fact that every added select adds another `<div id="serviceTemplate">` which is kind of bad practice to have non-unique ids on a webpage.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for the tips. Yes, the Clone will copy the id as well, event though id will only target the 1st match in DOM flow which is working. But this is not the right things to do, I updated use class + .first() to target the original element.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that update, thank you for pointing that out. This approach definitely has my approval.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will get to trying this later this evening. And thanks for the reminder about the ID--I was just trying whatever I could just to make this work even. (:

Comment: @RickYoder Cool, no prob